# Is there a simple way to count documented functions in a library?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Is there a simple way to count how many functions, methods and/or classes there are in a library? And how many are documented? Maybe through Doxygen output?

When I try to Google a solution all I get is algorithms to count things... :)

Comment: What do you have access to? Header files, documentation from the developer, dll?

Comment: something like this? https://github.com/alobbs/doxy-coverage

Comment: @Tas: I have access to sources.

Comment: @Xin: That looks very promising, I'm going to give it a try right away. Thanks!

Comment: @XinHuang: I think I can work with this. It reports the number of documented entities in each of the header files, not the aggregate. That should be simple to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Xin Huang pointed out in a comment above, there is a useful tool called `doxy-coverage.py` at https://github.com/alobbs/doxy-coverage. It prints, for each file documented with Doxygen, it prints how many entities it has (namespaces, free functions, classes, member functions, enums, #defines, etc) and how many of those are documented. It lists each of the non-documented entities. At the bottom it gives a summary of the documentation coverage (percent entities that are documented). It uses the XML output of Doxygen to do so.

I replaced the line

```
print("%d%% API documentation coverage" %(total_per))
```

by

```
print ('%3d%% API documentation coverage (%d of %d)'%(total_per, total_yes, total_all))
```

To add the total number of entities and total number of documented entities in the project.

It seems possible to modify the tool to distinguish entities by type. If I ever do this, I'll post the resulting code here.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool named [Coverxygen](https://github.com/psycofdj/coverxygen) which requires XML output from Doxygen.

Install it by:

```
pip install coverxygen
```

**Bonus:**
If you use Sphinx and Doxygen (and Breathe) to generate documentations, you can use [DocsCov](https://gitlab.com/AkibAzmain/docscov) to make a badge showing documentation coverage to show on your README.